# Can we lock or freeze a moving joint?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I want the wheels of a mobile robot to lock, say on some given command, so that there is no need to run the wheel controllers, and upon an unlock command to go back to usual behavior. I saw in DRC http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#Freeze that there is a freeze functionality. So, I was wondering whether this is possible or not.

Thank you

Peshala

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5153/can-we-lock-or-freeze-a-moving-joint?/) by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can do this programmatically using the physics API if you have a pointer to the Joint object. See the [Joint::SetHighStop](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a59848678cdca37a851e782f170f55c2b) and [Joint::SetLowStop](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#aeb7b0117576037c075c68cf4cf6e5282) commands. There is an example of using these commands in one of the physics tests ([test/integration/physics.cc:848](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/test/integration/physics.cc#cl-848)).

So my approach would be to get a pointer to the joint object, read the current joint position, then set the joint limits to be equal to the current position.

`gazebo::physics::JointPtr joint;
joint = getTheJointPtrSomehow();
// Get the current joint position
gazebo::math::Angle currentPosition = joint->GetAngle(0);
joint->SetHighStop(0, currentPosition);
joint->SetLowStop(0, currentPosition);`

That's how I would do it currently. It would be nice to have an API that would do this automatically. Please make a feature request on the [bitbucket issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues?status=new&status=open) if you have an idea for how you would like it to work.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-12-20**:
Thanks for your answer @scpeters I will try this and make a feature request.

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-12-20**:
and when we need to revert back to the original controller we can set: joint->SetHighStop(0, gazebo::math::Angle(10000000000000000)) where 1E16 being the default value set by gazebo for a continuous joint